# Dealing with asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have just started programming with JS and Node, and I haven't got used to asynchronous stuff yet.
Basically, i have the following code:

```
for (var i=0, len=sources.length; i<len; i++) {
    processSource(sources[i], function(info) {
        doesOtherStuff(sources[i], info);
    });
}
```

It doesn't really work, because, as `processSource` takes a while to finish, the function `doesOtherStuff` is called with unmatching arguments, like `sources[2]` and the processed info for `sources[0]`.

What is the correct way of dealing with this? Is there something inherently wrong with the design of these functions. (both processSource and doesOtherStuff are my functions).

Comment: "int" hmmmm, that seems wrong.

Comment: Typo, sorry =P. Problem still holds.

Comment: you show me a reason to use javascript forEach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code is the fact that `i` is not want you expect it to be.

When the loop completes, the function-level variable `i` has the value of sources.length. So when doesOtherStuff runs that is what the inner function uses.

```
for (var i=0, len=sources.length; i<len; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        processSource(sources[i], function(info) {
            doesOtherStuff(sources[i], info);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: So this is actually standard, is is it more like a hack to code that was bad-written in the first place? I'm still trying to get my head around event-driven.

Comment: That pattern is commonly called an IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression) in case you're looking for more information about it.

Comment: Love this, also we can do +function() {...}(i);    :)

Answer (score 1):

javascript style could help you:

```
sources.forEach(function (e) {
    processSource(e, function(info) {
        doesOtherStuff(e, info);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `var` instead of `int`.

2) You have a superfluous `)` in your call to `processSource`.

```
processSource(sources[i], function(info) /* No 2nd ')' here */ {
    doesOtherStuff(sources[i], info);
});
```

should work.

Comment: Sorry, those were typos, not actually the issue. Problem is indeed what epascarello has guessed.

Comment: To avoid typos you should never *type* code into SO but *copy* it from your source.

Comment: Sorry... The code was actually a little more complex, so i tried to reduce it to be clearer about the issue. Guess it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Caolan's async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) - this works on Node and in the browser. You can then do something like this:

```
async.map(sources, function (item, callback) {
    // Do your actions on each item here
    processSource(item, function (info) {
        var result = doOtherStuff(item, info);

        // Send callback so the next item can be processed
        callback(null, result);
    });
}, function (err, results) {
   // Handle the processed results here
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be an overkill? Or is this library used in the majority of node projects, (like Boost library to C++) ?